# Clone required message in typeError using Error Customization

Tags: yup

In `yup` we have [Error Customization](https://github.com/jquense/yup#error-message-customization), which allows us to create default error messages when we don't pass any error message to the schema.

Is it possible to define in the Error Customization a `typeError` message that will always clone the `required` message from the schema?

I.e.: I have this defined schema:

```js
export const employeeValidation = yup.object().shape({
  employeeFirstName: yup
    .string()
    .matches(REGEX_PATTERNS.name.pattern, REGEX_PATTERNS.name.err)
    .required('The employee name is required'),
  employeeLastName: yup
    .string()
    .matches(REGEX_PATTERNS.name.pattern, REGEX_PATTERNS.name.err)
    .required('The employee last name is required'),
  employeeEmail: yup
    .string()
    .email('Please enter the employee personal email address in format: theirname@example.com'),
  employeeNationality: yup.string().required('The employee nationality is required'),
  employmentCountry: yup.string().required('The employment country is required'),
  employmentState: yup.string().when('employmentCountry', (employmentCountry: any) => {
    if (EOR_SUPPORTED_PROVINCE_COUNTRIES.has(employmentCountry)) {
      return yup.string().required('You must select an option');
    }
    return yup.string();
  }),
  workVisa: yup.boolean().typeError('You must choose an option').required('You must choose an option'),
});
```

However sometimes the `employeeNationality` is `null`, which must trigger a validation error, but it triggers the `typeError`, which displays the default ugly error message. I want the `typeError` message to always be the same as the `required` error message, unless specified another message. Note that the `workVisa` has both messages defined, but it's an overkill to always specify they both equal.